# Is there a faster way than wp_insert_post to add content to a blog

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I've written a plugin which retrieves an xml file, parses and creates a series of short posts from the content.

Although each post is very short (sometimes just a single sentence, never more than a few sentences), there are around 1000 posts to create from the file.

Using wp_insert_post takes enough time for this job to timeout giving a 500 status.

I also encounter similar problems when deactivating the plugin and trying to move the same content.

Are there any quicker ways of populating (or removing) posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the database with an [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and add multiple rows at once.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
INSERT INTO $wpdb->posts (
`post_author`, 
`post_date`, 
`post_date_gmt`, 
`post_content`, 
`post_title`, 
`post_status`, 
`post_name`, 
`post_modified`, 
`guid`, 
`post_type`, 
`post_mime_type`
) 
VALUES
    ( $user_id, $current_date,$current_date_gmt, $content1 ),
    ( $user_id, $current_date,$current_date_gmt, $content2 ),
    ( $user_id, $current_date,$current_date_gmt, $content3 )
;
```

Make sure to fill all the values that are set to `NOT NULL` and have no `default` value in the post table schema.
From `wp-admin/includes/schema.php`:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->posts (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  post_author bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  post_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_content longtext NOT NULL,
  post_title text NOT NULL,
  post_excerpt text NOT NULL,
  post_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
  comment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  ping_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  post_password varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  post_name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  to_ping text NOT NULL,
  pinged text NOT NULL,
  post_modified datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_modified_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_content_filtered longtext NOT NULL,
  post_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  guid varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  menu_order int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
  post_mime_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  comment_count bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
  KEY post_name (post_name),
  KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID),
  KEY post_parent (post_parent),
  KEY post_author (post_author)
) $charset_collate;\n";
```

Also, regular posts need a default category. Not sure what happens if you omit that.

Comment: Thanks - any gotchas I should look out for with this approach? (i.e. what is it that wp_insert_post is protecting me from mucking up?)

Comment: @OwenStephens See my update.

Comment: It's just `$wpdb->posts`, not `$wpdb->prefix.posts`. +1 anyway.

Comment: Another thing: Normally there's a callback incrementing the count for posts for a tag or a category. You'll have to also add that manually, when looping through.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the API might save you a minute now but cost you hours later. I have done similiar things and run into timeouts but not 500, you should realy check the php and appache logs first to try and find the cuase.